Selenium stops at get method when accessing a specific site
Question
I am trying to access the following japanese site using chromedriver and selenium:
https://salonboard.com/login/
I am able to access other sites without any issues, but the process stops at the get method for this particular site.
Environment
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Node 18.6.1
Google Chrome 126.0.6478.61
Selenium 4.21.0
Sample Code
import { Builder, logging } from 'selenium-webdriver';
import { Options, ServiceBuilder } from 'selenium-webdriver/chrome';

(async () => {
    const defaultChromeFlags = [
        '--headless',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--window-size=1980,1200',
        '--disable-extensions',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        '--hide-scrollbars',
        '--single-process',
        '--no-zygote',
        '--ignore-gpu-blacklist',
        '--use-gl=swiftshader',
        '--lang=ja',
        '--disable-web-security',
        '--allow-running-insecure-content',
    ];

    const serviceBuilder = new ServiceBuilder();
    const builder = new Builder()
            .forBrowser('chrome')
            .setChromeService(serviceBuilder);
    const chromeOptions = new Options();
    // Create a logging preference
    const logPref = new logging.Preferences();
    logPref.setLevel(logging.Type.BROWSER, logging.Level.ALL);

    chromeOptions.addArguments(...defaultChromeFlags);

    // Set logging preferences
    chromeOptions.setLoggingPrefs(logPref);

    builder.setChromeOptions(chromeOptions);
    const driver = builder.build();
    await driver.manage().setTimeouts({ pageLoad: 2 * 60 * 1000 });
    await driver.get('https://salonboard.com/login/');
})();

I tried accessing the site using Selenium with the specified code. I expected the page to load without any issues as it does for other sites. However, the process hangs indefinitely at the get method for this particular URL. No errors are thrown, and the page does not load.
